# Returning average capacity from a list of product descriptions?

Tags: python, list, methods

Function Name: avg_capacity
Parameter: product_list - A list containing a sequence of product descriptions as strings.

Return: A floating point number that denotes the average of capacities as given in the list.

Description: Given a list of product descriptions where each element in the list is of the format 'product_id-capacity', calculate the average of all capacities and return the value.

Let us assume that you are the owner of a store that sells different masks. These masks come in shipments of boxes of a particular capacity. Each box of mask has a unique product ID (no two IDs are the same), and a capacity associated with the box. You want to find all the different capacities of the boxes, and calculate the **average** of these capacities.

Ex)

product_list = ['A1-10', 'B10-40', 'C403-50', 'D5-10']
return: 27.5

```
def avg_capacity(product_list):
    for capacity in range(len(product_list)):
        product_list[capacity] = product_list.split("-")
        average = capacity["-":]
        return average
        

print(avg_capacity(['C12-100', 'A10-400']))
```

I honestly have no idea how to approach this. I was told to use string methods, so I attempted to use split in order to split the product ID at every instance of a dash. However, I don't know how to manipulate the lists in order to take the numbers on the right side of the dash, and put them code that would take the average of every product ID in product list. Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 2):

```py
def avg_capacity(product_list: list[str]) -> float:
  capacities = [int(x.split("-")[1]) for x in product_list]
  return sum(capacities) / len(capacities)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your code:

- you call `product_list.split("-")`, but `product_list` is the list itself; you should call `split` on the individual elements, e.g. `product_list[capacity]` in your current code
- with `for capacity in range(...)`, capacity is an `int`, so `capacity["-":]` does not work; if you want the part after the `"-"`, get the `[1]` element after `split("-")`
- you never actually sum and divide the individual capacities, as would be required for the average
- you `return` in the first iteration of the loop; you probably want to return *after* the loop (after fixing the other problems)

You can try something like this:

```
def avg_capacity(product_list):
    total = 0
    for mask in product_list:
        name, cap = mask.split("-")
        total += int(cap)
    return total / len(product_list)
```

The above loop could also be condensed into a one-liner using `sum`:

```
def avg_capacity(product_list):
    return sum(int(mask.split("-")[1]) for mask in product_list) / len(product_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I appreciate it very much. One thing I have a question about is what does 'name' do? And why doesn't the function work when name isn't put before cap, but does work when it is? Thank you again

Comment: @jdavis29 That is "tuple unpacking". `mask.split("-")` always returns a list with two elements, which are distributed to the two variables `name` and `cap`. You don't actually need name, so you could also do e.g. `_, cap = ...`. You an also just do e.g. `parts = mask.split("-")`, but then you have to use `parts[1]` to access the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

```
def avg_capacity(product_list):
    capacity_list = []
    for capacity in product_list:
        capacity_list.append(int(capacity.split("-")[1]))
    return sum(capacity_list) / len(capacity_list)
        

print(avg_capacity(['C12-100', 'A10-400']))
```